# Find group of words in a text file and extract the line to new text file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

txt contains word "hi" "hello" "aloha" as per below

```
hi

hello
aloha
```

And I have one more file abc.txt which contains many words including the above 3 words. Now I developed a PowerShell script to search the words in abc.txt and extract the line containing the words to a new file `done.txt`. I use 
`-match` command to find the word.

How to use the file ref.txt which contains the words for the finding, instead of declare the words in coding?

I would like to develop it in cmd.exe instead of PowerShell.

```
$source = "C:\temp\abc.txt"
$destination = "C:\temp\done.txt"

$hits = select-string -Path $source -SimpleMatch "hi","hello","aloha"
$filecontents = get-content $source

foreach($hit in $hits)
{
    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-1]| out-file -append $destination
    "" |out-file -append $destination
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to convert this from PowerShell to batch, you will need to completely start over.  None of what you're doing is applicable to batch. If you're interested in doing this in PowerShell only, I can help you.  Are you interested?

Comment: That sounds like a simple `findstr /G:searchwords.txt abc.txt>done.txt` would do the job.

Comment: hi 1redOne..in that case im ready to go with powelshell :)..no issues and THANK U!

Comment: $hits = select-string -Path $source -SimpleMatch "hi","hello","aloha" $filecontents = get-content ---->this line replaced with

Comment: $hits = findstr /G:searchwords.txt abc.txt>done.txt $filecontents = get-content ---->with this? correct me pls if im wrong?

Comment: Stefan's suggestion is meant to be a cmd/bat answer based on _I would like to develop it in cmd.exe_

Comment: how if i wish to continue in powershel? i tried this but failed...$hits = select-string -Path $source -Match $ref ...where by i declare $ref = "C:\temp\ref.txt

Answer (score 1):

This should do the batch trick:

```
findstr /G:ref.txt abc.txt >> done.txt
```

This would print all lines containing the stings in `ref.txt` in `abc.txt` to `done.txt`

Have I understood you question correctly?

Comment: hi script_Coded..my question is to get the 'hello' word from ref.txt instead of type 'hello' in the coding..

Comment: Okey, so get the first line from ref.txt and search for it an then the second line and so on?

Comment: @Script_Coded: you can find all of them in one go with `findstr /G`

Comment: @Stephan Yupp! I'll change that!

Answer (score 0):

To cover the PowerShell aspect of this question...

To get the patterns you want from file is rather easy since [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) supports strings arrays for the `-Pattern` parameter. In its simplest form you could just do something like this

```powershell
$patterns = Get-Content c:\temp\ref.txt | Where-Object{$_}
$hits = Select-String c:\temp\test.txt -Pattern $patterns -SimpleMatch
```

Your file contained a blank which I was not sure was on purpose or not. I used `Where-Object{$_}` to filter that out just in case. Then just pass that string array `$patterns` to the parameter `-Pattern`.

The rest of your code after that could use a little tune up. There is *no* need to read the source file in a second time just to output the matches again. Your output is just the matching line with a newline following.

```powershell
$patterns = Get-Content c:\temp\ref.txt | Where-Object{$_}
$results = Select-String c:\temp\test.txt -Pattern $patterns -SimpleMatch
$results.Line | ForEach-Object{"$_`r`n"} | Set-Content C:\temp\out.txt
```

Probably not the best way to get the desired output but it should work regardless.